# what is the data format of tree layout in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, tree

I am new to tree layout and the data format mentioned for tree layout is given as

```
{
    "name" :"d3",
    "children": [{
        "name": "Syliva",
        "children":[
            {"name": "HTML5"},
            {"name": "CSS3"},
            {"name": "Javascript"}
         ]
    },{
        "name": "jh",
        "children": [
          {"name": "abc", "size": "3534"},
          {"name": "def", "size": "3534"}
        ]
    }
    ]
    };
```

My doubt is "Is there any other format for tree layout or this is the format we should pass in tree layout?"

Thanks for the help

Comment: Well, as how much I have used `D3.js` i didn't found any other layouts for Tree.  What you have provided is the Only One Layout in my Opinion.
If you Found any other than Please let me Know. :)

Comment: Actually i am new to this tree layout and i want to know in how many format we can pass the data into this layout

Comment: Yeah, I got you. but I'm saying that as per my knowledge of `D3` i have founded only this single Layout. :)

Comment: Mention Not...!!  :)